# Why is there such a large difference in memory usage for dataframes between pandas and R?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, memory

I am working with the data from https://opendata.rdw.nl/Voertuigen/Open-Data-RDW-Gekentekende_voertuigen_brandstof/8ys7-d773 (download CSV file using the 'Exporteer' button).

When I import the data into R using `read.csv()` it takes 3.75 GB of memory but when I import it into pandas using `pd.read_csv()` it takes up 6.6 GB of memory.

Why is this difference so large?

I used the following code to determine the memory usage of the dataframes in R:

```
library(pryr) 
object_size(df)
```

and python:

```
df.info(memory_usage="deep")
```

Comment: Pandas uses fixed dtypes to load data that may be bigger than the storage used in R.  There are arguments in the read_csv that can massively reduce memory usage.  Using different dtypes for numerics.  Int8 int16 and int64 are great examples.

Comment: I agree with Paul. This [link](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-load-less-data/) could be a great starting point to explore how you can reduce the size of the data set in Python. For reference see this awesome [resource](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#object-size) for an in-depth exploration of memory management in R.

Comment: thanks! I managed to reduce the size to 3.6GB in pandas by specifying dtypes, makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found that link super useful and figured it's worth breaking out from the comments and summarizing:

[Reducing Pandas memory usage #1: lossless compression](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-load-less-data/)

1. Load only columns of interest with `usecols`

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv('voters.csv', usecols=['First Name', 'Last Name'])
   ```
2. Shrink numerical columns with smaller dtypes

   - `int64`: **(default)** -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807
   - `int16`: -32768 to 32767
   - `int8`: -128 to 127

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv('voters.csv', dtype={'Ward Number': 'int8'})
   ```
3. Shrink categorical data with dtype `category`

   ```py
   df = pd.read_csv('voters.csv', dtype={'Party Affiliation': 'category'})
   ```
4. Convert mostly `nan` data to dtype `Sparse`

   ```py
   sparse_str_series = series.astype('Sparse[str]')
   sparse_int16_series = series.astype('Sparse[int16]')
   ```